# Bundle extras returning null

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I'm having some problems.

In a class "A" I have the code:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if ( extras == null ){
        Log.e("extras", "Extra NULL");
    }
    String arrayWatt = extras.getString("valoresWatt");
    String arrayHorario = extras.getString("valoresHorario");


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  --> this is returning NULL`
```

This method throws NUllPointerException. What is the problem here? Syntax?

---EDIT----
So sorry, I forgot this code:
(This code is from another class that starts the activity)

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("org.me.android",
                    "org.me.android.GraphViewDemo");
        i.putExtra("valoresWatt", watt);
        i.putExtra("valoresHorario", hora);
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot one piece of source code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the extras, this is what I would do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String arrayWatt = i.getStringExtra("valoresWatt");
String arrayHorario = i.getStringExtra("valoresHorario");
```

Comment: i dont know what happened, i'm already do it other times and wirk fine

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code you listed for getting the `Extras` located?  Are you overriding the `onCreate` method?  If so, make sure you call `super.onCreate(bundleVariableName)` before trying to work with the `Extras`.  So...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    // ...
    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (data != null ) {
        // should actually verify that the key exists, so:
        // if (data.containsKey("valoresWatt")) {
        // ... do something with the value
        String watt = data.getString("valoresWatt");
        String horario = data.getString("valoresHorario");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you say that this first line is returning null:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();  // --> this is returning NULL
```

From the [Android docs for Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras%28%29), it seems that the getExtras() method will return null if no extras have been added yet.

In that case, you may have to add your String extras by calling .putExtra(key, value) on the Intent object directly, rather than on its Map of extras, which doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the NPE crash

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if ( extras == null ){
    Log.e("extras", "Extra NULL");
} else {
   String arrayWatt = extras.getString("valoresWatt");
   String arrayHorario = extras.getString("valoresHorario");
}
```

Instead of

```
i.putExtra("valoresWatt", watt);
i.putExtra("valoresHorario", hora);
```

try

```
i.putStringArrayListExtra("valoresWatt", watt);
i.putStringArrayListExtra("valoresHorario", hora);
```

if it is an arraylist of strings.

Comment: yeah, you're right, but the extras is always null! i dont want this i want catch the strings